# CMD - List Modified File with User who changed

Tags: windows, shell, cmd, command-line, command-prompt

I have written a simple code which provides me with the filename, date, and time when the file was modified. How can I also output the user who changed the file?

```
forfiles /M *.txt /C "cmd /c echo @file @fdate @ftime"
```

Comment: You can't. For speed reasons windows turns off auditing. There are two steps to turn on auditing. First turn it on for files (slowing down all future file accesses as auditing settings have to be checked). Then in the files you want to know about set their auditing for what you want to know in the Permissions dialog. The information will be in the security log in Event Viewer.

Comment: Very informative, thank you! Since `dir \Q` provides the user... do you think there is a workaround?

Comment: No. `Dir /q` provides the owner of the file. Normally the person who created it. Ownership only allows one to change permissions on an object *even if they don't have permissions too*.

Comment: Interesting. Suppose Event View is enabled... could you please hint which command to look for in order to achieve what I've described?

Comment: In Security Options see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/basic-audit-object-access. Then right click folder and tell it to audit folder in Properties - Security - Advanced - Audit tab. To read eventviewer use a query like `wmic PATH Win32_NTLogEvent where  (EventIDentifier=52 and sourcename='Disk') get /format:csv`